# How to spoof the MAC on a wifi, Linux Mint 17, with NM?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, security, linux-mint

I can't find a reliable way to spoof my mac.
If I use the "clone MAC address" on network manager (I use Linux Mint 17, Cinnamon), I can't connect to my wifi. I tried everything, unless I remove the cloned MAC address, I can't connect. There's no limit in place, no MAC address filtering on the access point.
I even tried setting it up using a script on boot (after removing the default network manager and installing wicd, since the default will impose its configuration when connecting).
Also, defining the config using /etc/network/interfaces.

All I got was intermitent results, I booted up, sometimes I had the spoofed MAC, sometimes the real one.

Anyone has been able to get consistent results by any means on this distro?

Thanks.

Comment: Quit the NM, and use macchanger

Answer (score 1):

You can change your MAC using macchanger.

`sudo apt-get install macchanger`

then type as

```
          macchanger --mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX ethY
```

Here XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX stands for your MAC ID and Y stands for your device name ID for example Wlan0, Eth0.

Answer (score 0):

macchanger works but there is one caveat; you have to disable the connection before the MAC will change.  Example commands:

```
sudo ifconfig wlo1 down
sudo nmcli radio wifi off
```

Replace down with up, off with on to enable again.  The above are examples for *wireless* cards.  eth0, eth1, etc. for wired cards in the first line.  Google will be your friend when disabling the device you wish to change.

You can find your Ethernet (wired or wireless) with ifconfig but you should know that by now if you're attempting to change the MAC.